# Where is catkin_add_nosetests() documented?

Tags: ros, python, catkin, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently, that is the catkin way to run Python unit tests.

I can't find any documentation for it via Google.

UPDATE: For future reference: Dirk found it under [Development Documentation](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-add-nosetests).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57968/where-is-catkin_add_nosetests()-documented?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-06**:
+1. For Hydro it might be http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-add-nosetests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the CMake macros were self documented, at some point there were docs generated for them:

http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/macros.html

But now they seem to have gone missing. You can see the documentation for that particular macro here:

https://github.com/ros-shredder/catkin-release/blob/master/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake

I am not sure why we are not generating documentation for CMake macros anymore. Perhaps @Dirk Thomas can comment on that.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-13**:
Thanks for the pointer William. I opened a bug ticket on the missing docs: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/384

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-02-14**:
The link to CMake source code should be changed to https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/noetic-devel/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-02-14**:
Similarly the link to ROS documentation should be changed to https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_nose_configuration.html